# Calling ink! contracts not working

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, substrate-contracts-node

I have been trying to call the flipper ink! contract from polkadot.js contracts section I keep getting this error.
I've build the smart contract using cargo +nightly contract build and am using ink! v4 and cargo-contract 2

[image: error image]

Comment: Use https://contracts-ui.substrate.io/ until polkadot.js is not fixed

Comment: Yeah. Since it's currently working at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still WeightV2 isn't merged in polkadot.js you can [look this](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8538) PR. Because of that you are getting this error. Instead you can use https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/pull/8538 this one it works fine for now.

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked

Comment: considered make it as answer then! @VincentGitonga